# Characters removed when saving with $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, save

I have an textarea where I write javascript. I want to save the javascript-code with $.ajax(). The problem is that the + sign and everything after the first & is removed.

Is there anybody who have any tips on this one, or can give me an clue in the right directions?

This is my jQuery code:

```
$("#save").click(function(){
    var code = editor.getValue(); 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "save.php", 
        data: "id=1&code="+ code, 
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",
        success: function(html){             
            alert("Done");
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Either let jQuery handle the data serialization or use `encodeURIComponent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery automatically serializes the data for you so you can send an object instead:

```
$("#save").click(function(){
    var code = editor.getValue(); 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "save.php", 
        data: { id: 1, code: code }, 
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",
        success: function(html){             
            alert("Done");
        } 
    }); 
});
```